# What is the difference between `~/.guix-profile` and `~/.config/guix/current`

Tags: package-management, guix

I have just installed GUIX on top of my Arch Linux, however, I still have difficulties to understand some of the concepts. I understand that a *profile* is a selection of packages from `/gnu/store` and that I can enable them by sourceing `<profile-dir>/etc/profile`. However, I don't understand why I seem to have two "default" profiles, stored as symlinks in my home dir:

- `~/.guix-profile -> /var/guix/profiles/per-user/user/guix-profile`
- `~/.config/guix/current -> /var/guix/profiles/per-user/user/current-guix`

I was able to find some information, but not enough:

`.guix-profile`

> You can assign it the role you want. Typically you would install the manifest 
>   of the packages you want to use all the time.
>
> Alternatively, you could keep it "manifest-less" for throw-away packages that you would just use for a > couple of days. This way makes it convenient to run `guix install package-foo` and
>   `guix upgrade package-bar` ([from GUIX cookbook](https://guix.gnu.org/cookbook/en/html_node/Default-profile.html#Default-profile))

`.config/guix/current`:

> The result of running guix pull is a profile available under `~/.config/guix/current`
>   containing the latest Guix. 
>   (["Invoking `guix pull`"](http://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Invoking-guix-pull.html))

What is their difference of these two profiles? Why do I need these two? Do I need to source both on login?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## These profiles are default values

The only things that set these two profiles apart from "normal" GUIX profiles is that they are the default options of their respective GUIX commands (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/562882/what-is-the-difference-between-guix-install-and-guix-pull) for how these two are different):

- `~/.guix-profile` is the default option of the `guix package` option `-p|--profile=`
- `~/.config/guix/current` is the default option of the `guix pull` option `-p|--profile=`

They're generated on the first call of their respective companion commands if they didn't exist before.

But you can completely do without these two profiles if you wish and use user-defined profiles all the time (see below)

## They differ in their jobs: Provide a `guix` version itself vs. provide other programs managed by `guix`

- The profile `~/.config/guix/current` provides the binaries `guix` and `guix-daemon`. In the default configuration, this profile determines what is the most up-to-date version of all packages you can install. The list of packages you can install is tied to the guix version, in contrary to Nix. [This blog post explains why.](https://guix.gnu.org/blog/2018/multi-dimensional-transactions-and-rollbacks-oh-my/)

  - Concerning the user `root`, the binary provided by (the symlink target of) `/root/.config/guix/current/bin/guix-daemon` is the GUIX Daemon that is started automatically by the system. It also has got a symlink in `/usr/local/bin`.
- The profile `~/.guix-profile` contains any package you want it to contain. Many users include it in their shell startup files, so they have often-used programs  that don't belong to any other task-specific profile available automatically.

## The profiles are integrated in your workflow only via shell-startup files and you can decide if they are effective

Which profiles are relevant for you is only determined by your `.profile` (or `.bash_profile` or whatever shell initialization file you use)

If you specify nothing, you will use no packages from `guix` and the version of `guix` itself that `root` uses, because the [GUIX shell installer script](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Installation.html#Installation) creates a symlink `/usr/local/bin/guix -> /var/guix/profiles/per-user/root/guix`

If you include in your `.profile` (or similar)<sup>1</sup>

```
GUIX_PROFILE=$HOME/.config/guix/current; 
source "$GUIX_PROFILE/etc/profile"
```

you can use your own version of GUIX and package versions.

If you include

```
GUIX_PROFILE="$HOME/.guix-profile";
source "$GUIX_PROFILE/etc/profile"
```

you load a profile which you can define/change without using the `-p` parameter of `guix package`. Of course, you can also load any other profile here, you then just have to use the `-p` parameter if you want to change it. Many people use this profile to include commands they often need but which are not assigned to any task-specific workflow.

---

<sup>1</sup> In case you wonder why you need to define a variable before sourcing, read the source'd script. It will add the link to the profile to `$PATH` then, and not the profile folder itself. This means that you will automatically get updated package version if you call `guix package -u` without source'ing the profile again.

Comment: BTW, if I don't use Guix System, what is the proper way to include shell completions for `guix` command from default profile for guix itself (I mean `.config/guix/curret`), and from which user it should be taken: myself or `root`?

Comment: Dear @tosh, I don't know that and I think it is more helpful for other users if you create a new question for this, because search engines can find it and you can document there what you already know about your problem, avoiding duplicate work.

Comment: This answer should part of the official documentation! It has puzzled me no end...