# What is the difference between `guix install` and `guix pull`?

Tags: package-management, guix

Both packages seem to download packages and update some profiles, but why do I need both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For users coming from other package managers, the following rough analogies may apply. But don't infer too much from it, because GUIX allows every user to use their own set of packages and even their own version of GUIX!

`guix pull` is similar to `apt-get update` in that it downloads a new list of available packages, substitutes and derivations. However, it also installs a new version of GUIX for you!  (because of [reasons](https://guix.gnu.org/blog/2018/multi-dimensional-transactions-and-rollbacks-oh-my/))

`guix package -i` (synonym `guix install`) and `guix package -u` are similar to `apt-get install` or `apt-get upgrade` in that you can install/upgrade packages, but only, if you've gotten an updated package list (`apt-get update`/ `guix pull`) before.

## They change different profiles that exist for different tasks

- Per default, `guix pull` changes the profile `~/.config/guix/current`. This profile is for the task of creating profiles and everything related (e.g. installing packages).
- Per default, `guix install` or its synonym `guix package -i` changes the profile `~/.guix-profile`. This profile is for the job of doing whatever productive (?) work you are doing.

See [this SO question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561093/what-is-the-difference-between-guix-profile-and-config-guix-current) for more infos about those profiles

Comment: Also comparing `guix refresh` just for the sake of completeness would also be useful